# GitHub for Mac gives error after editing commit and publishing

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I'm using GitHub for Mac and syncing with the repository on GitHub.com. I edited a commit I had already published (probably shouldn't have done) to add another changed file to it. Then I hit commit and publish. I get this nice blank error message now every time I try to publish and no new commits are pushing to GitHub.com.

[image: blank GitHub for Mac error]

There are no conflict messages showing in the app. How should I try to resolve?

Comment: You have to force push it. But I don't know how to do it with GitHub for Mac. In console it would be `git push --force`. FYI it's not a good way if there are others using the repo

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Just did Repository menu and Pull. Now I can publish.